# java.lang.VerifyError: org/jboss/remoting3/remote/HttpUpgradeConnectionProvider

Tags: jboss, jms, wildfly

I have a spring boot application. This app need to listen to the messages from JMS topics deployed in another application (let’s say this application name is Topic) . This topic application runs on wildfly 11 and uses ActiveMQ Artemis.

Did the following things,

Pointed my JNDI properties to the Topic application’s address like below,

```
    java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
    java.naming.provider.url=http-remoting://topic-application-address:port
    java.naming.security.principal=username
    java.naming.security.credentials=password
```

Included the jboss-as-cli libraries in the Spring Boot application.

```
    compile group: 'org.jboss.as', name: 'jboss-as-cli', version: '7.2.0.Final'
```

When I start the Spring Boot application ,

I’m getting the below exception

```
    2019-03-07 08:43:45.384  WARN 5307 --- [main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.VerifyError: org/jboss/remoting3/remote/HttpUpgradeConnectionProvider]
    2019-03-07 08:43:45.385  INFO 5307 --- [main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'threadPoolTaskScheduler'
    2019-03-07 08:43:45.395  INFO 5307 --- [main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2019-03-07 08:43:45.395  INFO 5307 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
    2019-03-07 08:43:45.399  INFO 5307 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

This exception is thrown from jboss-client.jar. This jar is needed since I'm using

java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory

If i remove this jar, I'm getting below error

```
    2019-03-06 08:38:10.015  WARN 39134 --- [main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory]
```

So i'm in need of both these jars but not sure how to fix this error

Comment: What JDK are you using to compile / run ?

Comment: JDK version is 1.8.0

Comment: Did you tried restarting the server using VM argument `-verbose:class`.

Comment: You shouldn't use the cli but the client jar. And also i'm a bit lost there as the client GAV are org.wildfly wildfly-client-all 11.0.0.Final so you should use     compile group: 'org.wildfly', name:'wildfly-client-all', version: '11.0.0.Finall'

Comment: At this point there's no evidence that indicates ActiveMQ Artemis is involved here. The failure is happening at the JNDI level.